# Validation on meteor form submit with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, meteor

I am trying to control email by using jquery and meteor, I can take error message when I write wrong mail address but when I write true, page refreshes but doesn't save mail in database.

```
$('commentForm').validate({
    sendForm: false,
    valid: function() {  
        var ebulten=template.$('#cemail').val();
        var o={}
        o.ebulten=template.$('#cemail').val();
        Ebulten.insert(o);
        alert("it's done!");
        console.log("valid !");
    }
});
```

footer-layout.html

```
<template name="footerLayout">
    <div id="footer" class="footer">
        <div class="container">
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" action="" method="get">
  <div class="form-group"><span class="f-s-20 text-white">E-Bültene Kayıt     Ol</span></div>
  <div class="form-group"><input name="email" id="cemail"  type="email" class="form-control width-250 m-auto" placeholder="E-  Bültene Kayıt Ol" required></div>
   <div class="form-group"><button type="submit"  id="ebultenkaydet" class="btn btn-theme width-250">E-Bültene Kayıt Ol</button>                     
</div>
</form>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is jQuery.validate() installed? It's not standard in Meteor. You'd have to install something like https://atmospherejs.com/cramhead/jquery-validate A common pattern is to avoid the form submit altogether and just add a template event that handles the click on your submit button directly, in your case, `'#ebultenkaydet click'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding event.preventDefault() to your template submit event?

Comment: i tried that but same result.                           Template.footerLayout.events({
'click #ebultenkaydet': function(e,template){......

Comment: Ah maybe try changing the event from click to submit. This should make the event.preventDefault() kick in.